# Can Proxmox cluster be configured with dedicated nodes at Internet

Tags: proxmox

Is it possible to create a cluster of Proxmox hosts connected through Internet at geographically separate locations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. If you are running latest Proxmox 6.x version, no special setup are required. It's running Corosync 3.x with [Kronosnet](https://www.kronosnet.org/) which are unicast. You might still want to add some VPN for extra security layer between your hosts.

For a previous Proxmox versions multicast was used as a default transport. You have to either manually switch it to unicast where possible or add a Layer 2 VPN with multicast support. See this note on multicast: https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Multicast_notes.

Answer (score 0):

[Official documentation](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Cluster_Manager#pvecm_cluster_network_requirements) says that it probably won't work with high latencies (in practice 50ms+ latency would make it almost impossible to join and maintain quorum)